# Using SOAP with WSDL in python with the suds-py3 library: Why doesn't it show me anything when I use the following code?

Tags: python-3.x, soap, wsdl, suds

Using SOAP with WSDL in python with the suds-py3 library:
Why doesn't it show me anything when I use the following code?
What am I doing wrong?

config:

https://appweb.dane.gov.co/sipsaWS/SrvSipsaUpraBeanService?WSDL
https://appweb.dane.gov.co/sipsaWS/SrvSipsaUpraBeanService?xsd=1

```python3
from suds.client import Client

url = "https://appweb.dane.gov.co/sipsaWS/SrvSipsaUpraBeanService?xsd=1"

results = Client(url)
print(results)
```

**Solution:**
Solution to the problem: use the zeep library.
**implementation:**
https://github.com/oigonzalezp2024/cliente-webservice-sipsa/blob/main/etl/etl.py

[show console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIvoV.png)

Comment: I can see the WSDL but get an error when I open it by Soap UI.  WSDL has own an error. (Error loading [http://appweb.dane.gov.co:80/sipsaWS/SrvSipsaUpraBeanService?xsd=1]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "") So, suds can't process it.

Comment: @Bench Thank you very much for your comment. What alternatives do I have to be able to work? Will we have to use Java or can we use Python to create a client?

Comment: WSDL's problem means SOAP server's problem. So It can't be addressed by the client side.

Comment: Thank you very much, I already solved the problem. Change the library to Zeep. Here is the implementation. https://github.com/oigonzalezp2024/cliente-webservice-sipsa.